# From a table of all votes for all venues in all categories, how to extract the total of votes for each venue in each category

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of all votes for all venues in all categories, which goes a little bit like this:

| vote_id | user_id | venue_id | category_id | time | ip | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 0 | 4 | 7 | 2022-10-28 16:59:00 | 127.0.0.1 | 2022 |
| 25 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 2022-10-28 16:59:00 | 127.0.0.1 | 2022 |
| 26 | 2 | 9 | 7 | 2022-10-28 16:59:00 | 127.0.0.1 | 2022 |
| 27 | 3 | 1 | 10 | 2022-10-28 16:59:00 | 127.0.0.1 | 2022 |
| 28 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 2022-10-28 16:59:00 | 127.0.0.1 | 2022 |
| 29 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 2022-10-28 16:59:00 | 127.0.0.1 | 2022 |
| 30 | 6 | 7 | 6 | 2022-10-28 16:59:00 | 127.0.0.1 | 2022 |
| 31 | 7 | 10 | 2 | 2022-10-28 16:59:00 | 127.0.0.1 | 2022 |
| 32 | 8 | 4 | 10 | 2022-10-28 16:59:00 | 127.0.0.1 | 2022 |
| 33 | 9 | 1 | 10 | 2022-10-28 16:59:00 | 127.0.0.1 | 2022 |
| 34 | 10 | 1 | 1 | 2022-10-28 16:59:00 | 127.0.0.1 | 2022 |

The `vote_id` is a primary key, and a single `user_id` may vote for multiple `venue_id` and `category_id`, but that doesn't really matter. The only columns which I need to count are `venue_id` and `category_id`. In this test data, both the `venue_id` and `category_id` are random numbers from 1-10. In real data, they won't be, but they will be known, so I can insert them into the query manually if needs be.

I have an end result in mind, but I can't connect the dots sufficiently to work out how to get there. Ideally, I want a table of all venues set against a total of all votes in each category, like this:

| venue_id | category_id = 1 | category_id = 2 | category_id = 3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | total of votes for venue 1 in category 1 | total of votes for venue 1 in category 2 | total of votes for venue 1 in category 3 |  |
| 2 | total of votes for venue 2 in category 1 | total of votes for venue 2 in category 2 | total of votes for venue 2 in category 3 |  |
| 3 | total of votes for venue 3 in category 1 | total of votes for venue 3 in category 2 | total of votes for venue 3 in category 3 |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

Alternatively, I can also work with a total number of votes for any one category in a single query - there are only 16 categories in the real data, so I can run 16 separate queries if that's what it takes.

| venue_id | category_id = 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | total of votes for venue 1 in category 1 |
| 2 | total of votes for venue 2 in category 1 |
| 3 | total of votes for venue 3 in category 1 |
| ... |  |

All examples I've come across concern counting [the number of unique values in a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654978/using-count-to-find-the-number-of-occurrences), rather than agreggating data for a specific column and value, so I don't really know where to go from here. The closest I've come is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544409/how-to-count-occurrences-of-a-column-value-in-sql), but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: to do such queries you need dynamic sql search for it with pivot as search terms and start

Comment: @nbk Thanks, that's what I needed to set me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something similar to [this article](https://www.databasestar.com/mysql-pivot/), counting occurrences of rows with a specific category_id, like [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045124/count-case-and-when-statement-in-mysql#5045167). So my final code runs a little bit like this:

```sql
SELECT
venue_id,
SUM(CASE
  WHEN category_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) AS category_id_1,
SUM(CASE
  WHEN category_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) AS category_id_2
FROM votes
GROUP BY venue_id;
```